# The wrong communications in application of iOS, Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

There is an application which the list of employees has, and each employee can have several tasks. When clicking the employee his tasks shall open. Here application begins to work not correctly, namely opens all tasks, and not just for the specific employee.

Database scheme: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxSMtqa62EX9TGE5eVlwX1BoaU0

Project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxSMtqa62EX9RVIzcWtCaktpM0E

Clicking processing:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"empToTasks"]){
                NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.employees objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
                TasksViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
                destViewController.emp = selectedDevice;
                }
    }
```

Add task:

```
 - (IBAction)saveTask:(id)sender{

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        NSManagedObject *newTask = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tasks" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newTask setValue:self.tasksField.text  forKey:@"task"];
        [newTask setValue:self.dataTasksField.text forKey:@"dateTask"];


        NSError *error=nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Can't save %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription] );
        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ура" message:@"Успешно добавлено" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
```

View Task in table:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:`(NSInteger)section{
    return self.emp.task.count;
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
        UITableViewCell*cell1 =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Tasks *currentTask =[self.emp.task.allObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell1.textLabel.text = currentTask.task;
        return cell1;
    }
```

What needs to be corrected that tasks only of the specific employee were shown?

Comment: Where are you adding Task entity to Employee entity. i.e `[_emp addTask: newTask];`

Comment: @Khundragpan 
NSManagedObject *newTask = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tasks" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newTask setValue:self.tasksField.text  forKey:@"task"];
        [newTask setValue:self.dataTasksField.text forKey:@"dateTask"];
here!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is as you are saving/ adding Task data without any reference to the perticular  `employee` . And fetching the whole table . You should add 3rd key as a reference and add a predicate on that reference while fetching into `ViewDidLoad` of `TasksViewController` . to get perticular employee task .

Hope I got you correctly .